# How to Automate Plugins adding in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to automate code for adding plugins in eclipse IDE. Are there any ways to do it?
normally we use eclipse marketplace/install software to add our plugins. How to write automate code to do this for eclipse ide the same way?
Any script /java code to automate?

i need example code for automate plugin install for testng in eclipse ide

Comment: There are many ways to do this, e.g. via p2 director from the command line: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

Comment: could you explain

Comment: On the command line you can add/install one or more plugins using the p2 director (see link above). If you also want to configure Eclipse and check out Git repositories, have a look at Eclipse Oomph. Or you can build your own Eclipse IDE with or without your own update site and with or without automatic update enabled. To know what is best in your case, one would have to know your use case in detail and how much time you are willing to invest.

Comment: actually my question regarding want to install testng plugin in my eclipse -how to do automate process the shared link shows some configuration related which not clear to me

Comment: Please give me a flow how to write automate code for adding testng plugin in my eclipse ide

Comment: [This one](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse)? `eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/ -installIU org.testng.eclipse.feature.group` (the repository URL you can get from the Eclipse marketplace website and the `installIU` ID from the install dialog by clicking on _More..._).